# Changing server name in WPS/WAS 7.5

Tags: websphere, wps

After federating the node from a WAS to another DMGR application, the server name was automatically changed to server1.

Is there any way to change it to, for example, server2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> 1. **Create a new server template using your existing server configuration**.
>      a. In Admin console, go to servers > Websphere Application Servers
>      b. Click on "Templates" > "New" and select your current server (eg:server1) and click "ok"
>      c. Name the template (eg: MyServerTemplate) and enter a short description. Click "Ok" and save the changes
> 2. **Create new server using the template created in last step**
>      a. In Admin console, go to servers > Websphere Application Servers
>      b. Click on "New", Enter the desired server name (eg: server2) and Click on "Next"
>      c. Select the new template name created in the last step (eg: MyServerTemplate) and click "Next"
>      d. Select "Generate Unique ports" (unless you need the default ports and know how to manage it)
>      e. Click Finish and Save the changes
> 3. Now you will have two servers with identical configurations. **Validate the configs in the new server and delete the Old server with wrong name**.